# How to take Wikipedia code for Adaptive Simpsons to work for different function

Tags: c

How can I take the code from Wikipedia for Adaptive Simpson's method found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Simpson%27s_method#C) and make it work for the function `1/(1.1+cos(x))`?

When I change 'sin' to '1/(1.1+cos)' in

```
double I = adaptiveSimpsons(sin, 0, 1, 0.000000001, 10);
```

and compile it says:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('double' and 'double (*)(double)')
double I = adaptiveSimpsons(1/(1.1+cos), 0, 1, 0.000000001, 10);"
                               ~~~^~~~
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a *function* taking a `double` (say `x`) and returning a `double` which evaluates `1/(1.1+cos(x))`

Then pass that function into `adaptiveSimpsons`.

Comment: Sir, as per `math.h`, `cos()` is declared as `double cos(double x);`, so that should work, right?

Comment: Indeed but you're not passing that, rather an expression of double type. Cos on its own would be fine.

Comment: you are very right. thanks. and BTW, its not my question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

your function

```
adaptiveSimpsons(1/(1.1+cos), 0, 1, 0.000000001, 10);
```

get to the `cos` it tries to find out what it means, is it a variable? a macro?
what you probably want is:

```
Math.cos(x);
```

and include the `math.h`, more details [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/cos/)